# Approximation of $\arctan(\cot(\pi x))$ That is Integrable

Tags: integration, trigonometry, approximation

As per the title, are there any approximations of $\arctan(\cot(\pi x))$, with arbitrary error (that hopefully can be controlled by some parameter $k$ ) whose integral can be expressed with elementary functions. I know there's a Fourier series, but it requires more terms to get more accurate, and it can become computationally expensive to calculate.

Comment: @BrianMoehring As stated in the quesiton, I want a function that has some arbitrary error (that hopefully could be controlled by some variable).

Comment: The function *is* integrable:  $$\int \tan^{-1} \left( \cot (\pi x)\right)\ dx = \frac{\pi  x^2}{2}+x \tan ^{-1}(\cot (\pi  x))$$. Surely you consider trigonometric functions "elementary."  Calculated using Wolfram's *Mathematica*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, I know-- I checked-- but it isn't correct (at least the one you show-- it's the same answer from WolframAlpha).

Comment: @BrianMoehring The maximum absolute error in [0,$n$].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$.  Since $$\arctan(\cot(\pi x)) = \arctan(\cot(\pi\{x\})) = \arctan(\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi\{x\})) \\ -\frac{\pi}{2} < \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi\{x\} \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$ it follows that $$\arctan(\cot(\pi x)) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi\{x\}, \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}.$$

---

Arguably $\arctan$ and $\cot$ are both "elementary" functions, but this gives an exact way to write $\arctan(\cot(\pi x))$ without appealing to anything more than linear functions and the operation of "rounding down to the nearest integer".

It has as an antiderivative the function $$\int_0^x \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \pi\{t\}\right)dt = \frac{\pi}{2}\{x\}(1-\{x\})$$

Comment: Thanks! +1 and accepted!

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$ \arctan(\cot(\pi x))=\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi x+\pi\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor $$

so it is continuous on intervals $[n,n+1)$ for $n$ an integer.

Comment: I updated the question (forgot something). Does it change your answer? Also, what is $n$?

Comment: Are you looking for a continuous approximation?

Comment: If needed yes, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks, I left out part of the expression. I will fix it.